# JQuery: Floating share box like Mashable?

Tags: jquery, plugins, css-float

I am looking for a [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) plugin which can serve me the floating share box functionality just like [Mashable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashable) implement in their new design: http://mashable.com/2010/03/12/flickr-co-founders-startup-hunch-raises-10-million/.

In the left side on the page above Mashable has sharing options which stays on the screen when you scroll the page. I want to implement the same kind of functionality in my application, using a jQuery plugin.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution might be something like this:

```
p.pos_fixed
{
     position:fixed;
     top:30px;
     right:5px;
}
```

(source: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_fixed)

Comment: but the problem is my elements position from TOP is not fixed, its variable?

Comment: in that case, you might want to look up $(window).scrollTop(),  $('#float').position().top, $('#float').css()

Answer (score 1):

CSS can give the share box a fixed position in the browser. But it will not give the same effect as [mashable.com](http://mashable.com). You have to use jQuery in combination with CSS to achieve this.

Here is a good way to do it: [Add floating share buttons](http://codehacksblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-add-floating-share-buttons-to.html)